# SQL Enforcing a constraint that requires some logic

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, azure-sql-database, composite-key

I'm not sure how to word the question well enough for Google to be helpful - most results are about specifying a foreign key so that you can use a JOIN operator.

**Edit:**
To clarify, I have two main concepts here - a tracker, and a reading for a tracker. A tracker can have any number of inputs. A reading for a tracker has values *for each input on the tracker*, at that particular point in time.

```
Tracker
  Id
  Name
  Inputs (List)
    Name

Reading
  Id
  TrackerId
  DateRecorded
  Some other properties
  Inputs (List)
    Value
```

I have modeled this with the following structure:

```
Tracker
  Id              (Key)
  Name

TrackerInput
  TrackerId       (Key 0, Foreign key)
  Index           (Key 1)
  Name

Reading
  Id              (Key)
  TrackerId       (Foreign key)
  DateRecorded
  Some other properties

ReadingInput
  ReadingId       (Key 0, Foreign key)
  Index           (Key 1)
  Value
```

How can I, through SQL, enforce the following constraint:

> A reading *MUST* include a value for each input on the tracker that it references.

Comment: you can enforce it via trigger

Comment: A FK is when values for some columns in a table must also be values for some other particular columns & table. Your use of "FK" doesn't make sense. (In particular, "composite foreign key, which is currently split over two tables".) Can you say what you want without using it? In code please say what column list in one table references what column list in what other table. Also what does "inputs on" mean? Rows of the ...Inputs tables? PS You do not need PKs, FKs or any other constraints to hold or be declared in order to join.

Comment: A CK of a table is a unique column set that contains no smaller unique column set. A FK (foreign key) in a table t is given "(c,...) references u (d,...)" where {d,...} is a CK of u and if a row of t has values v,... for columns c,... then some row of u has values v,... for columns d,.... For each table, give its CKs & FKs.

Comment: Unfortunately your edit does not clarify. Please give example valid & almost-valid data for designs 1 & 2. Please confirm or correct this: "If (i,t,...,v_1,...,v_x)) is in Reading1 then some row (t,n,(n_1,...,n_x)) is in Tracker1".  What else is always true re the 2 tables? Also, given values for design 1, what values are in design 2 & vice versa? Do you mean, "(t,n,(n_1,...,n_x)) is in Tracker1 if & only if (t,n) is in Tracker2 and (t,1,n_1),...,(t,x,n_x) are in TrackerInput"? And similarly for Reading? (Design 2's constraint seems a relational division variant.)

Comment: In other words: Do you mean that `select index from Reading r join Tracker t on r.trackerId = t.Id where length(r.inputs) <> length(t.inputs)` is empty? Ie that `select 1 from Reading2 r join ReadingInput ri on r.id = ri.readingId group by ri.trackerId having count(*) <> (select count(*) from TrackerInput where t.trackerId = ri.trackerId)` is empty? PS Please read & act on [mcve].

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45865264/3404097

Answer (score 2):

> The inputs on a reading *MUST* refer to the inputs on the tracker, but it requires a composite foreign key, which is currently split over two tables. If I were to enforce a foreign key constraint, they would have to be joined:
>
> ```
> SELECT TrackerId, Index -- This is the foreign key I would like to enforce
> FROM Readings
> JOIN ReadingInputs ON ReadingId = Id
> ```

I guessed that version of your question that you meant that you would like to enforce that `Reading` & `ReadingInput` are subject to their join (hence that view/query) satisfying the constraint `foreign key (TrackerId, Index) references TrackerInput (TrackerId, Index)`.

You could do this declaratively by adding `Index` to `Reading`, dropping the current `Reading` & `ReadingInput` FKs and adding FKs

```
(TrackerId, Index) references TrackerInput (TrackerId, Index) -- Reading
(ReadingId, Index) references Reading (Id, Index) -- ReadingInput
```

Otherwise, you could use triggers.

Comment: I can't merge `Reading` and `ReadingInput` - I've updated the question to explain the relationship a bit more. I've never used triggers before, can you give a quick example of enforcing this through a trigger?